# Function to Overlay Bitmap not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I am Using the Function to Mearge the Two Bitmap File on One Another and it also overlay.
I am using this Function to Overlay it on OneAnother.

```
public static Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap cameraImage, Bitmap visionImage) { // can add a 3rd parameter 'String loc' if you want to save the new image - left some code to do that at the bottom 

     Bitmap finalImage = null; 
        int width, height = 0; 
          width = cameraImage.getWidth(); 
          height = cameraImage.getHeight(); 

        finalImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, cameraImage.getConfig()); 

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalImage); 

        canvas.drawBitmap(cameraImage, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(visionImage, new Matrix(), null);

        // this is an extra bit I added, just incase you want to save the new image somewhere and then return the location 
        /*String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png"; 

        OutputStream os = null; 
        try { 
          os = new FileOutputStream(loc + tmpImg); 
          finalImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os); 
        } catch(IOException e) { 
          Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e); 
        }*/ 

        return finalImage; 
      }
```

But After saving this Image I show that images to be combine with each other. it is not overlay. I want it to be Overlay on One Another.

Please tell me where i am wrong in this Function ??
Thanks.

Comment: you want combine bitmap's like one overlay another.

Comment: My first Image is of cameraPicture and Second one of the TransperentLayer. So I want the Second One transperent Image to be overlay on to the FirstOne Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the function to overlay two bitmap,s

```
private Bitmap overlayMark(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)    { 
    int bh = originalBitmap.getHeight();
    int bw = originalBitmap.getWidth();
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw,bh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0,0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: I have used your Function But the result is same as like before. I want the two images to be Overlay on One Another. But the Saved Image look like to be combine with each other and shown seperate in One Image file.

Comment: Your Answer is not going to work for me. I got the same result as i got before

Comment: can u post screen shot's what u get .

Comment: it was worked for me in my app, i was also done like that with image and transparent image on the original image.

Comment: Ok. There was some problem with the Device. Thats why i got the previous result. But ur code works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I have accept ur answer. But there is little problem. second image is Small compare to the first one. And I want it to be Overlay whole on the First Image. then what should i have to do ?

Comment: I want to set the Second Image height, width as like the First image then what should i have to do ?

Comment: create the trans parent bitmap with first image width and height.